# Trying to Store Image horizontally in Data table in C# ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to Store image in horizontally format in the Dataset to show in PDF.

In the Below Image we have 4 Images in the form of Row , I want to make it Horizontally.
[PDF Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HheKh.png)

Comment: Hi @Shubham Dwivedi, could you please share enough code to let us reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the page layout to landscape and divide image width according to page length.